# Is there a way to judge the quality of software design through commit?

Tags: design-patterns

For example, I have 2 class files (**ClassA and ClassB**) and each have 100 commits in the past week. However, all the commits of the **ClassA** are from the same developer, and **ClassB** is submitted from 100 different developers.

Intuitively, the design of the **ClassB** is bad, because too many developers modify this class, indicating that the design isolation is not good enough.

My question is whether there are theories or standards or indicators to measure this situation？

Many Thanks!

Comment: Why 100 different developers commit same class? what were the changes? is it a big class or configuration class?

Comment: There is a metric called [*"Hits of code"*](https://hitsofcode.com/) that goes through the commits and checks how many times a line has been changed. But this metric says nothing about the quality of code. It simply measures the amount of work put in.

Comment: big class, not configuration class

Comment: How many lines of code in the class? see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/66523/how-many-lines-per-class-is-too-many-in-java

Comment: Design quality is not a single dimension. Performance, readability, maintainability, etc are all design qualities. Your question might have a precise answer if you can nail down what you mean by quality.